# Asp.net Core 3.0 Separate Global Exception Handling for WebApi and MVC (including Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a filter to check for exceptions and return errors in json objects for my webapi.

In the same project, I have Razor Pages and MVC pages when exceptions are thrown, will return json objects.  How can I separate the two and use error pages for razor pages and MVC pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For separating exception handling for api and mvc, you could distinguish them by the request path, try something like below:

```
//use for mvc to return error page
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
//use for api to return custom object
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), subApp =>
{
    subApp.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
    {
        builder.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Error");
        });
    });
});
```